# MVVM with UITextField and UICollectionViewCell/UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, mvvm, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a bunch of full width/height `UICollectionViewCell`'s. Each cell has a `UILabel` with a title and a `UITextField` to edit that title "in-place",

My ViewController has an `AccessoriesViewModel` which holds # `Accessory` objects and it passes an `AccessoryViewModel` to my `AccessoryCell`.

The user can tap on `Edit` which locks the `UICollectionView` scrolling and sets the current cell in edit mode. The label is hidden, the text field is shown and the user can edit the name of the accessory.

**Problem**
The user should not be able to press `Done` if the name is of zero length and on pressing `Done` the function `updateName:completionHandler:` should be called on the accessory in question.

How do I achieve this the "correct" way?

**Idea A**
Let the ViewController be `delegate` for the `UITextField` and determine when the `Done` should be enabled/disabled. Finally calling `updateName:completionHandler:` on the accessory when done.

**Idea X**
?

Hope you can help me get on the right track.

I've put an example project up on GitHub [MVVM Editing](https://github.com/mbogh/MVVM-Editing)